# How do I clean up the static in this musical flyback transformer?

Tags: transformer, audio, high-voltage, flyback, music

So I built this musical flyback transformer off of Franzoli Electrctronics schematic,[image]
https://franzolielectronics.com/easy-flyback-i/.
I had to go the through hole method and it works. However, the music is not as crisp and clear as in his video. I am using a 24 V, 30 amp SMPS power supply to run it so power shouldn't be a problem.

https://youtu.be/DBukpYea4mQ

I have seen other videos based on his design that had crisp clear sound as well. I've searched Google for a while but I guess I can't get the key words right because I haven't found anything that seems remotely relevant.
Here's some pictures of the 1st iteration before I condense it down to a single board as well as a link to a video in my Google Drive.
[image: whole setup]
[image: the brains]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZohFMLkl2ioSb2XFePrvt_vjpHttri9L/view?usp=drivesdk

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Please include images and schematics. Not just videos, and upload them here to EE.SE, not to google drive.

Comment: @Hearth did as requested.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think I can help you much myself, but this should make it much easier for others to help.

Comment: Appreciate you helping me get it right @Hearth.

Comment: Your construction technique might be the problem. You’re switching high currents and there’s long wires on the mosfet. The circuit is also highly suspect.

Comment: @Kartman I did think of the MOSFET wires as part of the problem. I agree the circuit is suspect as well. I built it modular to ensure each part worked. I'm working on condensing to a single board with the MOSFET embedded to remove the wires. I just didn't want to use my limited supplies until I figured out the static.